# newlines when writing to a utf8 file

Tags: perl, utf-8

```
open OUT, ">:encoding(UTF-8)", "out.txt";
print OUT "hello\n";
...
```

I am writing several lines of text using code like the above.  The result is a file which does not show line breaks in a text editor or when outputted in a terminal window.

How are you meant to do line breaks when writing to a `utf8` encoded file?

Comment: Might be more of an OS issue, than of character encoding ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: That shouldn't have anything to do with encoding. The shown snippet has an extra `>`, in `">out.txt"` (you've already set it for writing in `">:encoding(UTF-8)")`; I don't know whether that matters though. Btw, if this is new code and you need utf8 across the whole program and all standard streams  you can just do `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8);` at the beginning and then use normal `open`.

Comment: That properly does line breaks (LF in unix and CRLF in Windows).

Comment: Here is a test: `perl -wE'use utf8; use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)"; $var = "↕"; open $fh, ">", "test_utf8.txt"; say $fh $var'`.  This one-liner correctly prints to file the up-down arrow.  (The `use utf8;` is there only so that I can enter it into the source.)

Comment: how about  just doing it as `open OUT, ">:utf8", "out.txt";`

Comment: @GerhardBernhard: The only difference that will make is that the printed data won't be checked for valid UTF-8 content.

Comment: I expect that you are running your Perl program on a different system from where you edit it. Please confirm.

Comment: It's very likely that you're doing this on Windows, or at least opening the text file on Windows in editor like Windows Notepad that doesn't know how to represent Unix's new lines. You may try to `print OUT "hello\r\n";`. Or try to open the resulting file in some more sophisticated editor like Notepad++. Also you may use Perl's input record separator variable `$/`: `print OUT "hello$/";` - it should hold 'CRLF' (`\r\n`) on Windows.